# Word 2007 document corrupt on a single PC

Tags: microsoft-office

One of my users has a word document about 8mb in size. It's about 30 pages and contains a number of pictures. When she tries to one the file it appears to be corrupt, with all her formatting lost and with the document now about 5000 pages long. Opening the same document from another PC on the network works correctly. Both machines use Word 2007.

I've tried re-saving the document on the pc it opens fine on, but even this new doc opens up in it's corrupted form on my user's PC.

Has anyone experienced this and come up with an explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the Microsoft Word Viewer - this should just be able to view the document straight-out without using any of the pre-installed Word dependancies. This should help you define whether it's the document or the application.

[Link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=3657ce88-7cfa-457a-9aec-f4f827f20cac&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

is it saved as a .docx file?  also have you tried doing a repair of the office install?

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody mentioned it before, when you're in the Open Dialog box in Word (or other Office Apps), the Open Button has a drop down on it's right side, the last option is "Open and Repair" for damaged files.